# Looping commands following an event using CQRS DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Lets say I want to delete all houses from a neighborhood when I delete the neighborhood (I'm really giving a random example). What I want to know is what would be the best practice in order to chain a set of commands following an event:

1)

- `DeleteNeighborhoodCommand` is dispatched from whatever point of entry
- `DeleteNeighborhoodCommandHandler` is triggered, deletes Neighborhood and dispatches `NeighborhoodDeletedEvent`
- `DelteHousesWhenNeighboorDeletedEventListener` is triggered, queries all houses from related neighborhood and dispatches `DeleteHouseCommand` one by one.
- `DeleteHouseCommandHandler` is triggered multiple times, deletes House and dispatches `HouseDeleted` event

2)

- `DeleteNeighborhoodCommand` is dispatched from whatever point of entry
- `DeleteNeighborhoodCommandHandler` is triggered, deletes Neighborhood, deletes each house and dispatches `NeighborhoodDeletedEvent` and X times `HouseDeleted`

It's important to note that we are in the same Bounded Context and we are dealing with Aggregates within the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

I would think Option 1 is a better choice, simply because you have simple disjointed actions triggered on `NeighborhoodDeletedEvent`.

In Option 2, you are hard-linking one of those actions (deleting houses) and also raising events that do not necessarily indicate the command that was just executed (`DeleteNeighborhoodCommand`).

Even when in the same bounded context and dealing with aggregates in the same domain, IMHO keeping things asynchronous and event-based like this helps you in the long term because it encourages clear segregation of responsibilities. No one single command takes on more than what it should handle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If Aggregate Root boundaries define a consistency boundary, wouldn't that mean that they should be encapsulated together as a single action ? I feel that doing option 1 is augmenting eventual consistency for a small gain in decoupling code. Also gain is relative as I it means that the logic is distributed across different set of actions but I guess everything is relative.

Comment: I assumed `Neighborhood` and `House` are two different aggregates. If they were part of the same Aggregate, then yes, it would make sense to change things as part of one transaction. Unless of course, you want to background a piece of the operation for performance reasons. But either way, when playing the long game, keeping pieces decoupled and small is what will help you remain agile and confident with increasing complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all depends on your model.

Is it *mandatory* that you need to delete all your houses after you delete a neighborhood? Are you using neighborhood just as a grouping for some specific domain process? In other words, is it mandatory for a house (invariant) to have a neighborhood?

I am thinking that maybe your houses don't need to be an AR, rather a collection of entities living in the Neighborhood AR.

You see, DDD is about MODELING, not so much about the infrastructure around it. Once you get your modeling the way you want, then the other pieces fall in place organically.

Let's say that they are two individual ARs, I would emit an event `NeighborhoodDeleted` and then, in the event handler, I would simply fetch all houses for that neighborhood and delete them from the repo. That way, you don't need to fire 200 commands just because your neighborhood had 200 houses.

But again, you need to model your domain correctly. You're never going to get it right the first time, so, don't stress too much. Just keep evolving it.